# Find all N-digit binary numbers with a limit of reps of 1 and 0

Tags: algorithm

Need some suggestions for an algorithm for the second part of the task with the R.

With input of two given posititve integers N and R find all N-digit binary numbers with
R the largest run length of each digit, the number of times the same digit can appear in a row in the number one after other as a sequence.

for R equal to 2,  2 is a maximum of digits 0 that can appear in a row in the number notation (next should be digit 1). The same is true for digit 1 sequences.

N can't be larger than 64.
Output can be unsorted

with input of

```
N = 5 R = 1
```

```
output:
1
10
101
1010
10101
Total: 5
```

---

```
input:
N = 4, R = 2
```

```
output:
1
11
110
1100
1101
10
100
1001
101
1011
1010
Total: 11
```

---

```
input:
N = 12, R = 6
```

```
output:
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111
1111110
11111100
111111000
1111110000
11111100000
111111000000
111111000001
11111100001
...
101010101011
101010101010
Total: 3903
```

Comment: Your example answers don't seem to match you problem statement -- they contain numbers with fewer than N digits, and the don't contain any sequences with a leading 0 digit.  For your N=5/R=1 example, there should only be 2 answers: `10101` and `01010`.

Comment: (if you consider the shorter sequences as having leading 0s, they often have too many consecutive 0s)

Answer (score 0):

According to your examples it seems you don't count leading `0`.
the following dynamic algorithm will work for you:

assume `f(N,R)` is the desired result for given `N` and `R`.
the first digits must start with `1` and could be sequenced in a row up to `R`.
so you could have 1,..,R `1` in a row at beginning of string.
so you have `f(N,R)=f(N-1,R)+f(N-2,R)+...+f(N-R,R)`
it's a recursive relation.
so if you can find the values of `f(1,R) ... f(R,R)` you can go forward and find any `f(N,R)`.
by following approach you can find the value `f(i,R) i<=R`
the difference here is like you don't have limit
for example if i=10 you just want set if integers A1..Ak which `A1+..+Ak=i` and because of `i<=R` the R wouldn't be limit here.
in this situtation `f(i,R)=2^(i-1)`
so you can easily fill `f(1,R) , .. , f(R,R)` and then go on for bigers `N`               as `f(N,R)=  f(N-1,R)+f(N-2,R)+...+f(N-R,R)`